# Update infor on a sheet from data introduced and saved in another one

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have 2 excel worksheets: W1 and W2.

W1 - It is a form like sheet. First i choose Month and Day and then i fill in with some data regarding that day (expenses, money received, etc.);

W2 - The data introduced in W1 is automatically transported to this one in a DataBase like Structure (Columns are months; lines are days. For each day i have Total expenses and Profit values).

My problem is: everytime i choose another Mont and/or Day in W1, the info regarding the previous day is deleted on W2, and i need that that info stays memorized.

Can anyone give a hint?

Thank you,

This is the formula i am using on W2 to get the info from W1:

=IF(AND(W1!$C$5=C$1;W1!$C$6=$A2);W1!$D$11;"")

IF the value on C1 is equal to the value on C5 of W1 (month name) AND the value on C6 is equal to the value on A2 (day number) than D11 (expenses of that day) otherwise ""

Comment: You will need to use VBA to transfer the data entered in W1 over to W2.  You can't use formulas for this (as you're finding out)

Comment: Can you help me with that. I don't know how to use VBA and i cannot find any solution around the web